# get single shape of selection

Tags: excel, selection, shapes, vba

I am currently wondering if there is a way to get single objects (shapes) of a selection.

I have the following selection:

```html
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("feed", "000-100-SRC", "product")).Select
```

How do I get the name of the first item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this

```
Sub Tester()

Dim v As Variant

    For Each v In ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("feed", "000-100-SRC", "product"))
        Debug.Print v.Name
    Next

End Sub
```

or like that

```
Sub Tester()

Dim vArr As Variant

    vArr = Array("feed", "000-100-SRC", "product")
    Debug.Print vArr(0)


End Sub
```

Comment: thank you did that but had:
dim v as shape --> my bad
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

basically your set of ranges is called a shaperange.

You can get its item like in any collection like : MyShaperange(1) , where myshaperange is a variable, or you replace it by activesheet.shapes(array("gggg","yyy"))(1)

If already selected, you can also: selection.shaperange(1) ,  but usually selecting ranges or shapes is not advised when coding.